# How to display a tableless model on rails admin dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rails-admin, activemodel

I am trying to display a particular model on dashboard (which does not have backend table ) but unable to do so.

The rails admin code does not picks it up and does not gets displayed on dashboard.

I have already defined the model configuration inside RailsAdmin initializer file.

Please suggest what could be missing here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post your configuration?
What do you expect adding the tableless to rails admin do?
I've been able to add tableless models that inherit from models with tables in the past. Is that the setup you want?
Have you tried adding self.abstract_class=true inside the class?

Comment: @Guillermo Siliceo Trueba As per the requirement, I had to add functionality for searching and retrieving documents from AWS S3, so I created **custom action** in rails admin that would redirect and fetch the details for further processing on it.  To display that link on rails admin dashboard, I had to create this particular model. Thanks

Comment: Oh i see, the custom action does not fit into any other model you have.
The admin dashboard action is not "embeded" into any model you can look into it to see how it works. Another option is to override the existing views, these are your options: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/tree/master/app/views/layouts/rails_admin

Comment: @Guillermo Siliceo Trueba Thank you. I will try overriding the existing view.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use a model without a table you can do this:

```
class YourModelName
  include ActiveModel::Model

  ...
  # Your code goes here, make sure you leave the persisted? method


  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes @SickLickWill, using this we get a model without table.  But in my application, we have used [rails_admin gem](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin) that picks up active record models automatically.  But when I turned this particular model tableless, it stopped displaying on the admin dashboard. It seems rails_admin gem picks up only active record models. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Reading https://github.com/railsadminteam/rails_admin/issues/1377 it seems currently ActiveModel is not supported yet. There had been some attempts back in 2012 but did not come into fruition.